# obtencion de token de validacion de sesion, python , libreria , requests

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests, response

Tengo un problema en particular con una conexion a un web con autenticacion, quiero conectarme atraves de la libreria requests de python y descargar una tabla, actualmente analizando la pagina despues de autenicarme me genera una cookie con el token pero en la misma carga parece que ese token cambia y genera un segundo que es el que me es valido para poder descargar la tabla , si usu el primero que me devuelve el request me dice que no es valido pero si manualmente tomo el segundo que se genera y lo coloco dentro de la peticion si me funciona.
espero ser claro ya que vengo comenzando con este tema y no conozco bien los terminos que se utilizan

Comment: o sea estas haciendo web scraping? si es dinamico, te recomiendo usar selenium, saludos

Comment: si correcto, @sysbot gracias por la sugerencia lo revisare